# Query with MAX and MIN value from all results

Tags: mysql

I want do a query for extract all results from db, and save the MAX e MIN value **of all results** (not for each row), without processing the returning array. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are row-based `max` and `min` values in SQL. Let's say you have a table that has a `Quantity` field. You can get its maximum value using

```
Select max(quantity) from Table
```

and its minimum value using

```
Select min(quantity) from Table
```

and you can combine those to get both at the same time

```
Select min(quantity) as Minimum, max(quantity) as Maximum from Table
```

Comment: Hi, yes I know that there are these operators, but I want extract the Min and Max about all results not for each row.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need?